# Web server vs servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, server

I read somewhere that web server is used only for static contents like html pages and web server identifies dynamic content and transfers control to application server.Also I read somewhere that web server contains web container which inturn contains servlet container and jsp container.Now I have a doubt that servlet and jsp is not a static content like html so how is it possible that servlet container exixts in web server?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is down to terminology.

1) Web Server: Handles HTTP requests and responses.

2) Servlet Container: **Extends** the web server to handle the lifecycle of Servlets (JSPs are compiled into Servlets)

3) Application Server: Refers to a framework like J2EE

Examples of application servers include: JBOSS and Glassfish (Java J2EE).  IIS is a web server  that supports the .NET framework.

Choose a server based on the software you are developing.  If you are developing a J2EE application then use JBOSS or Glassfish.  If you are only using JSP and Servlets, then use Tomcat.

Comment: "Application Server: Refers to a framework like J2EE"-what does it means?

Comment: Perhaps buy a book about J2EE? I spent three years at university learning about it.

Comment: The key thing to remember is that a container can contain static content and dynamic content.  It depends how they are designed.